# Favorite server OS and source control system for small project

Tags: linux, version-control, operating-system

I am starting a small project with one other developer and need to setup a dedicated system to house our version control and any other short-term needs the project may have.  Requirements for the server are:

- Free/open source OS.

  Must provide source control.

  Must run all the time.

That's it.  So I know there are about a thousand Linux-based server distros around that can accomplish this, but looking for success stories from anyone who has managed their own server(s) for a small project.  Which did you find easiest, most flexible, most powerful, etc?

Side question: favorite source control system and why?

Comment: should be community wiki or closed

Comment: This is an interesting question and probably good for people looking to keep their code to find what others might use.

Comment: Doesn't matter, it should be community wiki. This is subjective and argumentative.

Comment: it's only argumentative if we take it there.  let's be helpful to the guy instead.

Comment: And statements like your "Subversion is fine, but isn't as solid ... [as CVS}" surely won't make it argumentative, no?

Comment: IMO a question is "argumentative" if and only if it's an obvious troll, or, if the OP expresses a strong personal prejudice of his or her own, instead of asking a question that invites a variety of replies. Subjective questions aren't banned, only  questions that are "sujective *and* argumentative".

Comment: It's not on a community wiki because the question spans multiple communities on more than one topic.  And the question says "favorite," so of course it's subjective.  Looking for opinions, not facts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a dedicated Ubuntu server using [GIT](http://git-scm.com/) for version control. 
Managing private repositories with [gitosis](http://swik.net/gitosis). And it's been great.

> Manage git repositories, provide access to them over SSH, with tight access control and not needing shell accounts.
>
> gitosis aims to make hosting git repos
>   easier and safer. It manages multiple
>   repositories under one user account,
>   using SSH keys to identify users. End
>   users do not need shell accounts on
>   the server, they will talk to one
>   shared account that will not let them
>   run arbitrary commands.

It's robust, damn fast, and reliable.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like this is a startup like scenario and not within an existing organization. Is there any reason not to use a hosted solution? You should focus on your core competencies and not on administering an extra server if you don't need to. [XP-dev.com](http://xp-dev.com/) offers free and private 1.5GB subversion hosting. [Github](http://github.com/) offers reasonable $12/month plans for private repositories.

Say you lowball value your time at $25/hour. If you spend more than 1/2 hour per month either administering your server or having wonky problems that hamper your productivity, then it would be more effective to just buy the github account.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu server with subversion.  Ubuntu is one of the better stable flavors of *nix and better ability to do apt-get and keep applications up to date.  Subversion works the best with the ability to do hooks.

Answer (score 2):

Debian + Git

Very stable and a lot of support out there for both.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu+Mercurial.

I use Mercurial+ssh for private repositories and bitbucket for public repos.

Answer (score 0):

My server for a one-man project (just me) is running OpenSuSE 10.x.  It hosts a number of subversion source repositories.

OS and repository preferences are highly subject to personal preference.  I use OpenSuSE and Subversion, and they work for me.  I have used many linux distros, dating back to Slackware version zero-point-eight, believe it or not, and I like a lot of them.  I've used mahy repostories, including CVS, visual sourcesafe, clearcase, and subversion.  CVS is rock-solid and smokin'fast.  Subversion is fine, but isn't as solid or as fast as CVS, but it's good enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Well I use Fedora for this purpose, personally.  Reasons being that it is a branch off Red Hat, so experience with Fedora should help me if I ever switch to development on Red Hat (a common server choice).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you'll find [Cent OS](http://www.centos.org/) to be a good fit for your purposes. It takes RHEL (which is focused on stability) and removes the branding in order to make it free, OSS again.

I don't think that you really asked for a version control recommendation but I'll talk about that too.

- [Git](http://git-scm.com/) is very popular right now, particularly because it is Linus's baby. I think that it is overkill for your needs.
- Try [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) as it is the other popular open source choice. There are a lot of open source [continuous integration](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/) and [defect tracking](http://trac.edgewall.org/) systems that integrate with Subversion.

Answer (score 0):

Debian + SubVersion